# Simulate 100 AR(2) time series

Tags: r, time-series

I need help with R programming.

Simulate 100 AR(2) time series with sample size n= 50 and  e_t ~ N(0,1).

Model: y_t= 0.1*y_{t-1} + 0.5*y_{t-2} + e_t

My question is out of 100 how many models will follow AR(2).

I have posted the code for 10 simulation (for practice). From the output, it is clearly seen that  7 out of 10 follow AR(2). I need the codes to calculate that for me because I want the number of simulation to be 100.

Thank you in advance.

R codes:

```
     library(FitAR)
     set.seed(54321)
     n=50
     phi <- c(0.1,0.5)
     for(i in 1:10){
     yt <- unclass(arima.sim(n=n,list(ar=phi),innov=rnorm(n,0,1)))
     p=SelectModel(as.ts(yt), lag.max = 20, Criterion = "BIC", Best=1)
     fit.monthly <- arima(yt, order = c(p, 0, 0))
     my_coefficients =fit.monthly$coef
     my_coefficients=my_coefficients[!names(my_coefficients) == 'intercept']
     print(my_coefficients)}
```

Output:

```
   ar1        ar2 
   0.07786595 0.53429714 
   ar1        ar2 
   0.07786595 0.53429714 
   ar1        ar2 
   0.07786595 0.53429714 
   ar1        ar2        ar3        ar4 
   0.1324752  0.6986000 -0.1366014 -0.2661816 
   ar1        ar2        ar3 
   0.1762949  0.5444131 -0.1720464 
   ar1        ar2 
   0.07786595 0.53429714 
   ar1        ar2        ar3 
   0.1762949  0.5444131 -0.1720464 
   ar1        ar2 
   0.07786595 0.53429714 
   ar1        ar2 
   0.07786595 0.53429714 
   ar1        ar2 
   0.07786595 0.53429714
```

Answer (score 1):

```
library(FitAR)
set.seed(54321)
n=50
phi <- c(0.1,0.5)

count <- 0

for(i in 1:100){
  yt <- unclass(arima.sim(n=n,list(ar=phi),innov=rnorm(n,0,1)))
  p=SelectModel(as.ts(yt), lag.max = 20, Criterion = "BIC", Best=1)
  fit.monthly <- arima(yt, order = c(p, 0, 0))
  my_coefficients =fit.monthly$coef
  my_coefficients=my_coefficients[!names(my_coefficients) == 'intercept']
  print(my_coefficients)

  if(length(my_coefficients) == 2){
    count <- count + 1
  }
}

print(paste0("AR(2) model count is: ", count))
```

Answer (score 0):

#### Use the `rGARMA` function in the `ts.extend` package

You can generate random vectors from any stationary Gaussian ARMA model using the `ts.extend` package.  This package generates random vectors directly form the multivariate normal distribution using the computed autocorrelation matrix for the random vector, so it gives random vectors from the exact distribution and does not require "burn-in" iterations. Here is an example from an AR(2) model.

```
#Load the package
library(ts.extend)

#Set parameters
AR <- c(0.9, -0.2)
m  <- 50

#Generate n = 100 random vectors from this model
set.seed(1)
SERIES <- rGARMA(n = 100, m = m, ar = AR, errorvar = 1)

#Plot the series using ggplot2 graphics
library(ggplot2)
plot(SERIES)
```

[image]